# blender closed suddenly while using bge

Tags: game-engine

I made a game in blender game engine and had been testing it after each step. but after I finished making the game and pressed p to play it, it suddenly closed. at first it used to close after a few scenes but after some more attempts it closes immediately after the first scene. I could still edit the game and logic but couldn't play it. I tried to run it in .exe but it shows a message that blender isn't working it is some type of 32 bit problem. though my system is 64 bit.
please tell how to fix this issue. thanks in advance.